# How to assign Json response object to state object in react native

Tags: json, object, react-native, fetch-api

fetch response contain (Json) many keys and corresponding values i want to assign Json object to state object how we can implement?

i have tried following but not worked

```
....
      .then(responseobj => {
        this.setState({
          state_object:responseobj,
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, why it does not work? Any error?
Anyway I always create a new variable and put the responsejson of a fetch inside.
Try this:

```
.then(responseobj => {
    let responseToHandle = responseobj;
    this.setState({
      state_object: responseToHandle,
    })
```

The other solution could be that in the fetch function you cannot access to this object, I always create on the top of the class a variable named self. Then in the constructor component method I assign this to self and then all operations that requires this can be accessed by self object.

example:

```
import React from ........
//more of your imports......

var self;
export default class YourClassOrComponent extends Component{

  ......

 constructor(){
   super();
   self = this;
   ......
 }

// using setState inside a function with self -->
....
.then(responseobj => {
let responseToHandle = responseobj;
self.setState({ // <----- Note that I use here self instead of this
  state_object:responseobj,
})
.....
```

Thats all I can tell you with my knowledge, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
If you are using fetch library to make API calls. 

.then((responseobj) => responseobj.json())
.then((jsonResponse) => {
   this.setState({
     state_object:jsonResponse,
   }) 
})
```